# Simple cuda kernel add: Illegal memory after 2432 kernel calls

Tags: c++, c, memory, cuda

I build a simple cuda kernel that performs a sum on elements. Each thread adds an input value to an output buffer. Each thread calculates one value. 2432 threads are being used (19 blocks * 128 threads).

The output buffer remains the same, the input buffer pointer is shifted by threadcount after each kernel execution. So in total, we have a loop invoking the add kernel until we computed all input data.

Example:
All my input values are set to 1. The output buffer size is 2432. The input buffer size is 2432 *2000.
2000 times the add kernel is called to add 1 to each field of output. The endresult in output is 2000 at every field. I call the function aggregate which contains a for loop, calling the kernel as often as needed to pass over the complete input data.
This works so far unless I call the kernel too often.

However if I call the Kernel 2500 times, I get an illegalmemoryaccess cuda error.[image: profiling nsight cuda]

As you can see, the runtime of the last successfull kernel increases by 3 orders of magnitude. Afterwards my pointers are invalidated and the following invocations result in CudaErrorIllegalAdress.

I cleaned up the code to get a minimal working example:

```
 #include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <vector>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template <class T> __global__ void addKernel_2432(int *in, int * out)
{
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x  + threadIdx.x;
    out[i] = out[i] + in[i];
}


static int aggregate(int* array, size_t size, int* out) {

    

    size_t const vectorCount = size / 2432;
    cout << "ITERATIONS: " << vectorCount << endl;
    
    
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vectorCount-1; i++)
    {

         addKernel_2432<int><<<19,128>>>(array, out);
        
        array += vectorCount;
       
    }
    addKernel_2432<int> << <19, 128 >> > (array, out);
    return 1;
    }

    int main()
    {
  
    int* dev_in1 = 0;
    size_t vectorCount = 2432;
    int * dev_out = 0;
    size_t datacount = 2432*2500;
   
    std::vector<int> hostvec(datacount);
   
    //create input buffer, filled with 1
    std::fill(hostvec.begin(), hostvec.end(), 1);
    
    //allocate input buffer and output buffer
    cudaMalloc(&dev_in1, datacount*sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc(&dev_out, vectorCount * sizeof(int));

    //set output buffer to 0
    cudaMemset(dev_out, 0, vectorCount * sizeof(int));

    //copy input buffer to GPU
    cudaMemcpy(dev_in1, hostvec.data(), datacount * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    
    //call kernel datacount / vectorcount times
    aggregate(dev_in1, datacount, dev_out);
    
    //return data to check for corectness
    cudaMemcpy(hostvec.data(), dev_out, vectorCount*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
   
    if (cudaSuccess != cudaMemcpy(hostvec.data(), dev_out, vectorCount * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost))
    {
        cudaError err = cudaGetLastError();
        cout << " CUDA ERROR: " << cudaGetErrorString(err) << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "NO CUDA ERROR" << endl;
        cout << "RETURNED SUM DATA" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 2432; i++)
        {
            cout << hostvec[i] << " ";
        }

    }
   
    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}
```

If you compile and run it, you get an error.
Change:

size_t datacount = 2432 * 2500;

to

size_t datacount = 2432 * 2400;

and it gives the correct results.

I am looking for any ideas, why it breaks after 2432 kernel invocations.

What i have found so far googeling around:
Wrong target architecture set. I use a 1070ti. My target is set to: compute_61,sm_61 In visual studio project properties. That does not change anything.

Did I miss something? Is there a limit how many times a kernel can be called until cuda invalidates pointer? Thank you for your help. I used windows, Visual Studio 2019 and CUDA runtime 11.

This is the output in both cases. Succes and failure:

[[image: success 2400 elements]

Error:
[[image: error 2500 elements]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static int aggregate(int* array, size_t size, int* out) {
    size_t const vectorCount = size / 2432;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < vectorCount-1; i++)
    {
        array += vectorCount;
    }
}
```

That's not `vectorCount` but the number of iterations you have been accidentally incrementing by. Works fine while `vectorCount <= 2432` (but yields wrong results), and results in buffer overflow above.

`array += 2432` is what you intended to write.

Comment: what a bad oversight from my part. Thank you :)